# Windows10にAccessRuntime(32bit版)をインストールすると、既存のOfficeが消えてしまう問題

Tags: ms-access

Office32bitが入っているPC、もちろんWindows10ですが、
そこにMicrosoft 365 Access Runtimeをインストールすると、それまで入っていた
Office(Word,Excel,Outlook)が消えてしまう問題が時々発生しますが、
これはどうして起きるのでしょうか。そして回避する方法はないのでしょうか。

現況は、消えてしまった場合はsetuo.office.comからMicrosoftアカウントで
ログインして、プロダクトキーを入れてダウンロードしなおすといったことをしています。

Word,Excelだけならそれでもいいのですが、Outlookが消えるとアカウント情報などが
消えてしまうため、設定のし直しとなってしまい、大変苦痛です。

お分かりになる方がいましたら、原因と対策をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

Comment: この辺のことも色々と絡んでいそうです。[同じ PC にインストールできる Office 製品について](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/homeuse/attention4.aspx), [異なるバージョンの Office を同じ PC にインストールして使う](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf) `これは、言語パックや校正ツールだけでなく、Visio、Project、Access Runtime などの Office ファミリーの他の製品にも適用されます。`, [Access Runtime をダウンロードMicrosoft 365インストールする](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9), [同一コンピューターでクイック実行および Window インストーラーを使ってインストールされた Office はサポートされない](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/30775ef4-fa77-4f47-98fb-c5826a6926cd)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。上記の記事を確認したのですが、そもそもエラー表示などは表示されず、無事に完了したと出ておいて、実はこっそり消えているといったケースのため質が悪いです。もっと確実な情報があればよいのですが。